# Knowing type of response probability using glm in R

Tags: r, response, glm

I'm using `glm` function in R to predict, based on a response variable of type factor, that has the following levels *positive*, *negative*.

I want to know how to interpret the predictions when using `predict` (with type=response), because they're probabilities, but of which level, positive or negative?

Comment: Have you read [this](http://data.princeton.edu/R/glms.html)? It's an excellent explanation of `glm` in `R` especially `binomial glm`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do

```
levels(your_y_variable)
```

The first level is used as reference and the model predicts to probability of the second level. You can change the reference using `relevel`.